# AttributeError: 'NoneType' on selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, kivy

I have a error in my code, I want to get or to print the product text but when i run it it gave me an error.

here is my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from selectorlib import Extractor
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    product: product
    size_hint: .8, .8
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    spacing: dp(100)
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDTextFieldRound:
        id: product
        hint_text: 'Enter a product'
        icon_left: 'magnify'
        on_text_validate: app.System()

'''


class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    product = ObjectProperty(None)

    def System(self):
        print(self.product.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

it always gave me the next error

```
   File "C:/Users/Yesnia/Desktop/PYTHON/Apps development/App/App_Checking_Store.py", line 34, in 
   System
   print(self.product.text)
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you build your kv string but have no way to reference it. There are many ways to mend the situation, heres an example.

```
KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    ###product: product ### this does not achieve anything, you're just giving
    #some generic box layout a product attribute. this does not assign the App attribute.
    size_hint: .8, .8
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    spacing: dp(100)
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDTextFieldRound:
        id: product
        hint_text: 'Enter a product'
        icon_left: 'magnify'
        on_text_validate: app.System()

'''


class Main(MDApp):
    product = ObjectProperty(None)
    my_kv = None
    def build(self):
        self.my_kv = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.product = self.my_kv.ids.product
        return self.my_kv

    def System(self):
        print(self.product.text)
```

notice the comment i've left in your kv string, the addition of the new my_kv attribute to your App class, and the changes I've made to your build function.

Hope this helps!